# PIL not saving PNG images correctly on windows

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to save an image as a PNG using PIL on python. It works great on any Linux machine I try, but when I try a Windows machine the output images is completely transparent. If I try to save it as a JPEG it works fine. Any ideas?

```
bg1 = Image.new('RGBA', screen_size, (255,255,255,0))
...
bg1.save(path, 'PNG')
```

vs

```
bg1.save(path, 'JPEG', quality=100)
```

Comment: Does your image have transparency, or is it OK to just crop that channel out?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the new image, the fourth component of your RGBA values is the alpha. By setting it to 0 you are telling every pixel to be completely transparent. Try setting it to 255 if you don't actually want any transparency:

```
bg1 = Image.new('RGBA', screen_size, (255,255,255,255))
```